# Iterating through DataGridViewRow columns

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

How can I iterate through `DataGridViewRow` columns? I just want to get the number of columns that I have and go through them and get the values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Cells` property to get all values row have

```
foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
{
    get value by    cell.Value
}
```

and number of columns is equal to number of cells