# How to loop through the selected values in a dataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, datagridview, .net-3.5

At the moment, I am looping through values in a textbox:

```
List<string> result = textBox2.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();

for (int ii = 0; ii < result.Count; ii++)
{
// do something with value ii here
}
```

How do I use a dataGridView instead?  So instead of having a textbox which contains the values I want to loop throw.  I want to have a datagrid full of values, then select the values in the datagrid which I want to loop through.

Is this possible?  If so, how?

So just to clarify, I do not want to loop through the entire dataGridView.  I only want to loop through the selected rows of the dataGridView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, trying to understand the context of your question, you can use 
[DataGridView.SelectedRows Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows(v=vs.110).aspx)

Probably something like this:

```
foreach (var row in dataGridView.SelectedRows)
{
    // code here...
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it.  Got that bit working, just can't find the properties in `row` within the loop to extract the correct data from the correct column of the dataGridView.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015625/iterating-through-datagridviewrow-columns

Comment: Use DataGridViewRow instead of var and you can access the Cells values.
row.Cells[0].Value;